# How can I define a TTL index on a MongoDB schema using NestJs

Tags: typescript, mongodb, mongoose, nestjs, schema

I am currently using Nest's SchemaFactory to setup my MongoDB models. Here is a link to their documentation:
https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/mongodb#mongo

I was wondering how I could set a TTL index using this abstraction. I want every instance of a specific model to delete after 15 minutes.

Answer (score 2):

```
@Schema({})
export class Test {
  @Prop({ type: Date, expires: 900, default: Date.now })
  createdAt: Date;
}
```

Or:

```
@Schema({ timestamps: true })
export class Test {
  // ...
}

export const TestSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(Test);
TestSchema.index({ "createdAt": 1 }, { expireAfterSeconds: 900 });
```

Answer (score 1):

The documentation that you linked has the following section:

> Alternatively, the `@Prop()` decorator accepts an options object argument ([read more](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html#schematype-options) about the available options). With this, you can indicate whether a property is required or not, specify a default value, or mark it as immutable. For example:
>
> ```
> @Prop({ required: true })
> name: string;
> ```

Taking a look at the Mongoose docs, there is a special option for `Date` types, [expires](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#schemadateoptions_SchemaDateOptions-expires). This leads me to believe you could create a TTL index by including a Date field like so:

```
@Prop({ expires: 900 }) // `expires` is in seconds
timestamp: Date;
```